# In content page, the jquery document ready event fires before the content page is loaded

Tags: jquery, asp.net, master-pages

I have a master page that references jquery + jqueryui. Everything is fine.
In the content page I placed:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#tabs").tabs();
    });
```

It turns out that the ready event fires BEFORE the html of the content page is loaded :/.
So, how to determine when the whole content page is loaded ?

Edit this is my markup:

master page:

```
<form runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
  <Scripts>
    <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1-vsdoc.js" />
    <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.min.js" />
  </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

content page:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <div id="whatWorkedWellDiv">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>What Worked Well</legend>
            <br />
            <label for="user">
                Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="user" value="" /><br />
            <label for="emailaddress">
                Email Address:</label>
            <input type="text" name="emailaddress" value="" /><br />
            <label for="comments">
                Comments:</label>
            <textarea name="comments"></textarea><br />
            <label for="terms">
                Agree to Terms?</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="terms" class="boxes" /><br />
            <input type="submit" name="submitbutton" id="submitbutton" value="Submit" />
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    <div id="whatCouldHaveGoneBetterDiv">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>What could have gone better</legend>
            <br />
            <label for="user">
                Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="user" value="" /><br />
            <label for="emailaddress">
                Email Address:</label>
            <input type="text" name="emailaddress" value="" /><br />
            <label for="comments">
                Comments:</label>
            <textarea name="comments"></textarea><br />
            <label for="terms">
                Agree to Terms?</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="terms" class="boxes" /><br />
            <input type="submit" name="submitbutton" id="submit1" value="Submit" />
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</div>
```

Jscript:

> $(document).ready(function () {
>               $("#tabs").tabs();
>           });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `frames/iframes` this may be possible, since the `.ready()` handler would fire on that DOM in which it is actually executed.

Another way this could happen is, if you 'afterload' some parts of your site `asyncronous`.

Whatsoever, if you have different DOMs in your site, you need an individual `.ready()` handler in all of them.

If you don't have any of those constelations, please provide your html markup.

Comment: I have updated my question with the markup.
I am not doing any dynamic loading or frames/iframes...

Comment: @Vladimir: where do you insert your javascript ? Did you try to do a simple `alert()` within `.ready()` or access a DOM element ?

Comment: the javascript is inserted in a separate file.
The problem is that the document ready is executed when the master page is loaded, not when the content page is loaded.

Comment: @Vladimir - Are you using an UpdatePanel?  To the client there is no idea of a master page, it's just one big chunk of HTML sent down, regardless of how the server assembles it.

Comment: Well, it appears that the jquery call must be placed after all the divs in the content page.

Answer (score 1):

I got this working by moving the

```
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="Scripts/DocumentReadyScript.js"></script>
```

from the

```
<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
```

section to the

```
<asp:Content runat="server" ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
```

section

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in your MasterPage

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src='<%=ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js")%>'></script>
```